# Group 3 bytes together after the first one

Tags: vb.net, hex, arrays, midi, midi-instrument

I have a text file called "MyHex.txt" in it the file has these values

```
F0 43 00 0A 00 4f 91
```

i am opening my file with my Sub like this and trying to check if the first byte in array is "F0" then Set The value. the i need to group the next three bytes together and then the next three bytes and so on

```
 Dim strings As String() = IO.File.ReadAllText(C:\MyHex.txt).Split(" "c)


    Select Case strings((0))
        Case "F0"
            StatusType = "Sysex"
    End Select
```

Update:
Need to group the values every three bytes. so they can be decoded

Using

```
       Sn.xx.yy

       S=Status (8-e)
       n=CN (0-F)
       xx=FDB (00 -7F)
       yy=SDB (00-7F)
```

Update 2:

After removing Sysex "Header" im left with this

First Dump:

```
08 0A 4C 4D 20 20 4E 53 45 51 31 20 46 30 30 30 30 31 46 38 45 30 43 30 36 30 32 34 36 34 30 32 37 46 46 35 46 32 60
```

Second Dump

```
08 0A 4C 4D 20 20 4E 53 45 51 31 20 46 30 30 30 30 31 46 38 45 30 43 30 36 30 32 36 36 34 30 32 37 46 46 35 46 32 5E
```

the 29th byte and last are the only ones that change.

Comment: I do not understand your question at all after the "update:". What are those 4 cryptic lines of code?

Comment: You cannot decode like this; system exclusive messages do not contain other messages (status bytes are not allowed inside a SysEx). This particular SysEx is a vendor-specific Yamaha command; you'd have to look into the manual to be able to decode it.

Comment: CL... you are right... yes i do have with me the manual. and yes it is a Yamaha Digital Sequencer Recorder. that is where i got the sn.xx.yy formula from. I am dumping the sysex from the qx5, i have made 2 dumps. 1st has a C1 note playing for 1 full bar and 2nd has D1 playing for 1 full bar also....after removing the The sysex command F0 43 00 0A and the last byte F7   there is only two bytes that change. lok at  update 2.

Comment: stakx this is Midi Sysex decoding for Midi